# Como tomar una variable dada por un controlador php retornarla con una vista y luego usarla con vuej

Tags: javascript, laravel, json, vue.js

CONTROLADOR LINEA DONDE RETORNO LA VISTA CON LA VARIABLE

```
return view('busqueda', compact('proyectos'));
```

CODIGO EN VUEJ

```
var search = new Vue({
el: '#buscar',
data: {
busqueda:'' ,
proyectos: {!! $variable !!}
},
methods: {
buscar: function (event) {

axios({
  url: '/busqueda/',
  method: 'get',
  params: {
busqueda:this.busqueda
  }
}).then(response => {
  location ="/busqueda";
  this.list= response.data
});
}
}
})
```

NOTESE QUE EN ESTA LINEA TRATO DE PASAR LA VARIABLE PHP QUE ES UNA COLECCION A UN OBJETO EN JAVASCRIP

```
  data: {
    busqueda:'' ,
    proyectos: {!! $proyectos !!}
    },
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siempre el error se presenta en esta linea

proyectos: {!! json_encode($proyectos) !!}

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente al pasar colecciones de Laravel (y en general más de un elemento en PHP) a JavaScript, es necesario codificarlas como json, para lo cual json_encode() es suficiente:

```
{!! json_encode($proyectos) !!}
```

Comment: me da error igual amigo justo en la linea que me describes, este error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !"

Comment: acabo de subir una imagen donde se ve mejor el error

Comment: ¿es un archivo de blade? se puede ver claramente que no lo está interpretando blade

Comment: claro la vista que retorna esta en blade, alguna solucion?

Comment: Nunca había visto ese error, no pareciera estar ahí el error. ¿Probaste poniendo un array estático en JS? O pasando una variable sin escape.

Comment: si aun a si me da error de sintaxis, estoy tratando de descartar que pasa

Comment: Por lo visto el error está en otra parte del código JS

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   var tuVariable = @json($tuVariable);
</script>
```

Para mas info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data

Comment: recuerda que no es solo poner el código y ya, debes explicarlo; de lo contrario tu aporte se considera de baja calidad